# Filter array and append li items

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm creating Twitch TV as Freecodecamp challenge. I'm trying to get online and offline channels, I get it but there is an issue when I'm trying to loop filtered array.

**Problem is that looping through filtered array creates one addition li, and doubles one of array's element.**

**For example: ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch5 and blank li.**

Here is some code:

```js
function loopChannels(array) {
  for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    $("h3").eq(i).html(array[i].display_name);
    $(".logo").eq(i).attr("src", array[i].logo);
    $(".status").eq(i).html(array[i].status == null ? "offline" : array[i].status);
    $(".link").attr("target", "_blank");
    $(".link").eq(i).attr("href", array[i].url);
    a.append(title);
    li.append(img,a,stat);
    ul.append(li);
  }   
}

$("#online").on("click", function() {
  var online = channels.filter(c => c.status !== null);
  console.log(online.length);
  loopChannels(online);

});
$("#offline").on("click", function() {
  var offline = channels.filter(c => c.status == null);
  console.log(offline.length);
  loopChannels(offline);

});
```

EDIT: Channels array
[image]

Comment: Just a side-note: rather than `for` loop, you can use map: `array.map((index, item)=>{//do stuff to item and index})`

Comment: What's in the channels array?

Comment: Instead of a `for` loop, you could use `forEach`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: you are not removing old element thats why its doubling elements on ui

Comment: @Nick that's an array that I push all channels I get from request..

Comment: @PranayRana I tried to empty ul element, doesn't work.

Comment: updated answer have look

Comment: Is it possible to post the contents of the channels array? Your code looks reasonable so maybe the problem is in the channels array?

Comment: @Nick edited post..

Comment: @PranayRana It doesn't work, doesn't loop filtered ones..

Comment: @PranayRana Actually it stays the same, like without remove..

Comment: can you share at jsfiddle

Comment: codepen: https://codepen.io/merko30/pen/oqmdaz

Comment: Could it be because I declared elements in the function ?

Comment: working on your code , reply you soon

Comment: updated full source for you , have look its working now ,  please do accept/upvote if work

Comment: next time onwards , please remember to share code , so it will help you to get answer and helps who is answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully working code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdRzeq

Some of changes in orginal code are

1. Made use of jquery to create element dynamically specially li and its child
2. made use of `empty()` jquery function to clear out elements under `UL` , so it will show fresh list of online and offline channel based on criteria

based on code provided by you i created full jquery based code which is as below and its working

```
var streamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

var channels = [];
var online = [];


function loopChannels(array) {

var ul = document.querySelector(".streamers"); 

  array.forEach((ele,i)=> {

    var li = $("<li/>", {'class' : 'streamer'}).appendTo(ul);
    var img = $("<img />", {'class' : 'logo', "src": ele.logo}).appendTo(li);
    var stat = $("<p />", {'class' : 'status', "html": ele.status == null ? "offline" : ele.status}).appendTo(li);;
    var a = $("<a />",{'class' : 'link',"target": "_blank", "href": ele.url }).appendTo(li);
    var title = $("<h3/>",{'class' : 'strTitle','html':  ele.display_name }).appendTo(a);
  });
};


streamers.forEach(function(streamer) {
  $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/" + streamer + "?callback=?", function(data) {
  channels.push(data);
    loopChannels(channels);
  });
});


$("#online").on("click", function() {
  var ul = document.querySelector(".streamers"); 
  $(ul).empty();
  var online = channels.filter(c => c.status !== null);
  console.log(online.length);
  loopChannels(online);

});

$("#offline").on("click", function() {
  var ul = document.querySelector(".streamers"); 
  $(ul).empty();
  var offline = channels.filter(c => c.status == null);
  console.log(offline.length);
  loopChannels(offline);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort :)